# How to approach this strange error when working with the flextable library in R?

Tags: r, flextable

I'm trying to use the `flextable` library to make tables in RMarkdown (on an RStudio server). I'm getting a strange error message and can't make any progress on figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting this error message: **Error in UUIDgenerate(n = nrow(uid), use.time = TRUE) :
unused argument (n = nrow(uid))**.

NOTE: The error occurs when I tried to run the code within the RMarkdown document to the console. The code below (and error output) occurred in an R Script.

This code below produces the error:

```
library(flextable)

ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))

ft

Error in UUIDgenerate(n = nrow(uid), use.time = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (n = nrow(uid))


head_ft <- flextable(as.data.frame(mtcars))

head_ft

Error in UUIDgenerate(n = nrow(uid), use.time = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (n = nrow(uid))


sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)


packageVersion("flextable")
[1] ‘0.5.11’
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the package `uuid`. This issue is solved in the latest releases of flextable, so updating `flextable` should also update `uuid` automatically

Comment: I've now updated everything and am getting a new error: Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'border.bottom'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code. Any thoughts on why this might be?